# Pull-up resistors required on both side of level shifter?

Tags: i2c, level-shifting

My I2C sensor and my embedded processor do not agree on the logic level. So I need a level shifter. Normally I would put a pair of pull-up resistors on the SDA/SCL lines. With the level shifter in the middle, do I need to provide pull-up resistors on both side?  Or can it be either side?

Comment: Depends on the shifter. What implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using TI's txs0104e - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf

Comment: Reading the datasheet you supplied you'll see that device has 10kΩ pullup resistors integrated into it. You don't need to add any.

Comment: thanks. You can post your comment as an answer and I will vote for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Neither side, in this case.**

Reading [the datasheet you supplied](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf) you'll see that device has 10kΩ pullup resistors integrated into it.

You don't need to add any.

For other implementations, it may be required to add a pullup to one or both sides. Always read the datasheet, the answers are usually there.